# Count occurrences of value in row

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a row in my `mySQL` database called `"status"`. In that row i got three different values, either `"S", "R" or "L"`.

Whats the easiest way to count and output the number of occurrences of each value with php?

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT status, count(1) AS statuscount FROM <tablename> GROUP BY status`

Comment: Or just [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) if you *really* have a list and want to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a full look at your database, but the basic structure is this  (assuming you have another row called id)

**Edit: to demonstrate in php**

```
$dbc = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);    
$query = $dbc->query("select id, count(status) as status_count
    where status = 'S'
    group by id");
$query->fetch_assoc();
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['status_count'];
```

OR if you have more than one row do it like this:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo $row['status_count'];


}
```

Comment: Sorry for my incompentence, but how would i output this with php?

Comment: I just edited it to show a basic call of the query and then an echo of the row.

Comment: I tried that, but sorry to say it returns nothing. I also created a new row called "status_count" and added FROM table_name to the query, anything im missing? My table consists of three rows: id, status and status_count

Comment: run the query first in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the counts as separate rows with:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) as count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY status
```

You can get them in a single row with:

```
SELECT SUM(status = 'S') AS s, SUM(status = 'L') AS l, SUM(status = 'R') as r
FROM yourTable
```

After this, you can read a single row of results:

```
$row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$s_count = $row['s'];
$l_count = $row['l'];
$r_count = $row['r'];
```

Answer (score -2):

The better way its to use a mysql query using COUNT

You can count all the raws 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASE
or one raw
SELECT COUNT(colum_name) FROM DATABASE

To be more easy you can give it a variable name like this:
SELECT COUNT (Colum_name) as name FROM DATABASE

So an example,after you connect to your database
Use this:

```
$ query = mysql_query ('SELECT COUNT (R) as R   FROM status');

$ result = mysql_fetch_array ($ query);

Echo $ result ['R']
```

Hope this will help you !